# Using Log for Volley Post Method

Tags: android, android-studio

I am using Post Method to send data to server and the data includes strings and images values images value are send through multipart now i am getting some error to reslove i want to post all my data in Log to see where the data is not able to send can any one help me out to use log for all the paremeters values include image string values in log

Post Method Sample

```
 private void new_processing() {
        String URL = "Url";
        VolleyMultipartRequest volleyMultipartRequest = new VolleyMultipartRequest(Request.Method.POST, URL,
                new Response.Listener<NetworkResponse>() {
                    @Override
                    public void onResponse(NetworkResponse response) {
                        Log.d("response", new String(response.data));
                        rQueue.getCache().clear();
                    }
                }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
            @Override
            public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), error.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
            }
        }) {


            @Override
            protected Map<String, String> getParams() throws AuthFailureError {
                Map<String, String> params = new HashMap<String, String>();
                    if (action_taken == "Sample Taken " ||action_taken.equals("Sample Taken ")) {
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        json2.put("sampletype", product_type);
                        json2.put("samplecode", sample_code);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }

                    JsonArray sample_obj = new JsonArray();
                    sample_obj.add(String.valueOf(json2));
                    params.put("Raid_Sample", sample_obj.toString());
                    params.put("Raid_Action", null);



                } else if (action_taken.equals("Sale Stoped") || action_taken.equals("Licence Cancelled") ||action_taken == ("Licence Cancelled") || action_taken.equals("Licence Suspended")) {
                    JSONObject json2 = new JSONObject();
                    try {
                        json2.put("actiontype", action_taken);
                        json2.put("actiondate", lic_date);
                        json2.put("letterno", lic_letter);
                        json2.put("copyno", lic_copy);

                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }


                    params.put("Raid_Action", String.valueOf(json2));


                    params.put("letterfile", image_letter);
                    Log.i("action_object", String.valueOf(json2));
                }

                params.put("AuthID", AuthId);
                params.put("producttype", product_type);

                /* params.put("raidother", raid_type_other);
                params.put("violationother", voilation_other);*/
                params.put("dateofraid", raid_date);
                params.put("locationname", location_name);
                params.put("locationaddress", location_address);


                JSONArray array;
                array = new JSONArray();
                for (int i = 0; i < movieList1.size(); i++) {
                    JSONObject movieObject = new JSONObject();

                    try {
                        movieObject.put("name", movieList1.get(i).getName());
                        movieObject.put("designation", movieList1.get(i).getDesignation());
                        movieObject.put("postingplace", movieList1.get(i).getPostingplace());
                        array.put(movieObject);
                    } catch (JSONException e) {
                        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
                }

                memberlist = String.valueOf(array);
                Log.i("arraylist", memberlist.toString());
                params.put("Raid_Team", memberlist);

                return params;
            }

            @Override
            protected Map<String, DataPart> getByteData() {
                Map<String, DataPart> params = new HashMap<>();
                long imagename = System.currentTimeMillis();
                params.put("picurl1", new DataPart(imagename + ".jpge", getFileDataFromDrawable(bitmap)));

                return params;
            }
        };


        volleyMultipartRequest.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(
                0,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES,
                DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
        rQueue = Volley.newRequestQueue(ScrollingActivity.this);
        rQueue.add(volleyMultipartRequest);


    }
```

Comment: Instead of log, have you tried debugging? Add a breakpoint at certain code lines and execute the app in debug mode. Once the debugger reaches the line of code, you can verify the values directly in the Android Studio

Comment: @AtishAgrawal sir but at break point how will i get to know that this parameters gets its value?

Comment: Add breakpoints at `JsonArray sample_obj = new JsonArray();` and then debug each line to check what values are being added in the params. Similarly add other breakpoints to different parts of the code, like `Log.d("response", new String(response.data));`, `rQueue.add(volleyMultipartRequest);` etc.

Comment: sir i am not able to debug the app can uh help me out with log method  if its possible ?